# Dapper Output parameter interpreted as null by mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I am trying to run this simple Dapper example from the test suite in Mysql 5.6.10 (AWS Aurora).

```
var p = new DynamicParameters(new { a = 1, b = 2 });
p.Add("c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction:ParameterDirection.Output);
cnn.Execute(@"set @c = @a + @b", p);
var results = p.Get<int>("@c");
```

However, an exception is being thrown. The @c is being interpreted as NULL>
[image]

I would like to use two output parameters to return the number of rows affected by an insert statement and the last inserted ID.

Comment: Reproduced on connector 6.9.5 and Dapper 1.42. (and local MySql 5.6.14)

Comment: Definitively the problem is not in Dapper itself. That syntax _set @c = @a + @b" is invalid for MySql also in a standard (non Dapper) query.

Comment: As @Steve notes: if it isn't valid syntax for your flavor of database  server, it just isn't going to work. Dapper makes things more convenient, but it doesn't change what the server supports.

Answer (score 1):

I found it seems impossible to fetch out parameter from mysql with dapper, so I modified you code a bit to achieve the result.

```
var p = new DynamicParameters(new { a = 1, b = 2 });
//p.Add("c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
//conn.Execute(@"set @c = @a + @b", p);
using (var reader = conn.ExecuteReader(@"set @c = @a + @b; select @c;", p))
{
    //var results = p.Get<int>("@c");
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        var result = reader.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
```